# Cannot connect with mongoose and mockgoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use [mockgoose](https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose) (2.0.3) with mongoose (4.0.2) so that I can run my unit tests without a mongo server.

And as far as I can tell I'm using it correctly

```
import mockgoose from "mockgoose";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let mongooseMock = mockgoose(mongoose);
```

I then pass the mongoose instance in to my module which invokes the schema

But when I run my test I get

```
{ [MongoError: mock: connect failed] name: 'MongoError', code: 13328 }
```

And I have absolutely no idea why, it should just work out of the box.

Comment: Did you try using ES5 syntax?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue. You have to call `mongoose#connect(url)` after `mockgoose(mongoose)` but before running any tests.

More specifically I created a new module

```
var mockgoose = require("mockgoose");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mockgoose(mongoose);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");

module.exports = mockgoose;
```

and `require` it at the top of each test file that uses mockgoose. I haven't tried it with the es6 syntax but I think the main issue remains calling `connect` regardless of whether you use `require` or `import`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was to do with the version of mockgoose. I was using the latest experimental build `5.0.0-rc.5` when I should have been using the latest official build.